# rails 3 email sending problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I am using Rails 3 and implementing the email sending feature. I am not sure if my configuration is correct, but here are my codes:

**mailers/user_mailer.rb**

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "user@gmail.com"

  def send_to(user)
    @user = user
    subject='welcome !'
    mail(:to=>'y.lan@gmail.com', :subject=>subject, :content_type => "text/html")
    mail.deliver
  end
end
```

**controller**:

```
def CarsController < BaseController
  ... 
  def register_finish
    UserMailer.send_to(user)
  end

end
```

**config/enviroment.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     :address => "smtp.googlemail.com",
     :port => 532,
     :arguments => '-i'
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
   }

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

When my controller invoke 'register_finish' function and try to send email to a user, I always get **Timeout::Error (execution expired)** error message, what could be the reason??

I saw some people define the configuration in **config/initializers/setup_email.rb** and use

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = { ...}
```

while I configure it in **config/enviroment.rb** and use:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {...}
```

I also saw some people invoke "deliver" method inside controller while I invoke it inside 'UserMailer'.

**My questions**:

1. What's the difference between my implementation and the above different way of implementations I found from internet.
2. Why I got timeout errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm also using gmail as my smtp server and I've adder setup_email.rb to initiliazers containing this code

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
   :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
   :port                 => 587,
   :domain               => "domain.pl",
   :user_name            => "username",
   :password             => "password",
   :authentication       => "plain",
   :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

and it works for me :)

EDIT

I've just notice we are using different servers, maybe try with my config?

Comment: wait for it, it may come after a while ;)

Comment: then check if smtp username and password are correct, and double sure if you're checking right email

Answer (score 2):

Timeout errors mean that there is some authentication errors.

This line is no longer needed:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

While it is adviceable to set the smtp_settings in an initializer.

If you are using it on a development machine this configuration should work with gmail:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:enable_starttls_auto => true,
:address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
:port => 587,
:domain => 'your_domain',
:authentication => :plain,
:user_name => 'your_gmail_username',
:password => 'your_gmail_password'
}
```

EDIT

you can add for a development machine:

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000"
```

[Very good railscast on subject](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3)

Comment: where to put it, in config/enviroment.rb or in config/initializer/setup_email.rb???

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:
http://lindsaar.net/2010/3/15/how_to_use_mail_and_actionmailer_3_with_gmail_smtp

Works nicely for me