# Sending email with Rails 3 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gmail, mailer

I am learning to how send email with Rails 3 with [Agile Web Development Book, Task H](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails). However, I keep getting the following error:

```
ArgumentError in OrdersController#create

wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
Rails.root: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rails_projects/TUTORIALS/depot

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/mailers/notifier.rb:4:in `order_received'
app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:57:in `block in create'
app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:52:in `create'
```

I have looked at similar discussions on [gmail configuration,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026098/sending-email-from-gmail-rails-3) using [setup_mail.rb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313177/sending-mail-with-rails-3-in-development-environment) here and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298147/rails-3-email-sending-problem), but wasn't able to remove the error.

My config/environment.rb file (because i want same for dev/test/production)has my gmail details with xxxx and yyyyy:

```
 Depot::Application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => "gmail.com",
    :authentication => "plain",
    :user_name => "xxxxxx@gmail.com",
    :password => "yyyyyyy",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
end
```

model/notifier/order_received.text.erb has this:

```
Dear <%= @order.name %>
Thank you for your recent order from The Pragmatic Store.
You ordered the following items:
<%= render @order.line_items %>
We'll send you a separate e-mail when your order ships.
```

and finally, models/controller/orders_controller has def create method with the line Notifier:

```
def create 
   @order = Order.new(params[:order]) 
   @order.add_line_items_from_cart(current_cart) 
   respond_to do |format| 
      if @order.save Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id]) 
          session[:cart_id] = nil 
          Notifier.order_received(@order).deliver 
          format.html { redirect_to(store_url, :notice => 'Thank you for your order.') }
      else 
          format.html { render :action => "new" } 
          format.xml { render :xml => @order.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end 
   end 
end
```

I feel my email configuration was probably not done correctly, but not sure which one. Thanks!

**EDIT**: I managed to solve it! Instead of smtp i used sendmail.
As for the number of arguments error, the app/mailers/notifer.rb looks like this:

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => 'Sam Ruby <depot@example.com>'

  def order_received(order)
    @order = order
    mail :to => order.email, :subject => 'Pragmatic Store Order Confirmation'
  end

  def order_shipped(order)
    @order = order
    mail :to => order.email, :subject => 'Pragmatic Store Order Shipped'
  end
end
```

Although my emails and everything still works, i'm curious whether anyones know why the smtp doesn't work, and sendmail does.

Comment: This is the full one: `def create
    @order = Order.new(params[:order])
    @order.add_line_items_from_cart(current_cart)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
        session[:cart_id] = nil
        
        Notifier.order_received(@order).deliver
        
        format.html { redirect_to(store_url, :notice => 'Thank you for your order.') }
      
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @order.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end`

Comment: @Sayanne: please *edit* your answer and put the code from the `create` action in it rather than leaving a comment.

Comment: @Ryan: Thanks! Included the complete create method and removed the spaces too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a space in your `order_received` definition:

```
def order_received (order)
```

That should be this:

```
def order_received(order)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it this line in `create`?

```
if @order.save Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
```

If that's what you really have then Ruby will try to pass whatever `Cart.destroy` returns to `@order.save` as an argument, the above is equivalent to this:

```
if(@order.save(Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])))
```

However, the [`save` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#method-i-save) doesn't take any arguments so you get a "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) in OrdersController#create" error message. I'd guess that you mean:

```
if @order.save
  Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
  # etc.
```